# Unable to return the sum of an object array property

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to return the sum of an object property from an array.
I managed to get this done in another component, but fail to redo it in another.

I get the following error: `this.cartitems.forEach is not a function"`

Below is the a working example:

```
<template>
<div id="shopcartpreview"  v-if="carthover">
    <div class="cartitem" v-for="item in cartitems">
        <div class="cartitempic"><img class="productImg" width="80px" 
   height="80px" v-bind:src="'assets/products/' + item.image"></div>
        <div class="cartitemdetails">
            <div class="cartitemname">{{item.name}}</div>
            <div class="cartitemqty">{{item.qty}} X </div>
            <div class="cartitemprice">€{{item.unit_price}}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="cartitemdelete">
            <img src="assets/images/icon-bin.png" width="15px" 
    height="15px">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="carttotal">
        <div class="carttotaltext">TOTAL:</div>
        <div class="carttotalprice">€{{Total}}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cartcheckouttbn">PROCEED TO CHECKOUT</div>
    <div class="viewcart">VIEW CART</div>



</div>    
 </template>
 <script>
  module.exports = {
    data: function () {
            return{ 
                cartitems: 0,
                carthover: false
            }
    },
    created(){ 
        EventBus.$on('addToCart', (payload) =>{
            this.cartitems = payload
        }),
        EventBus.$on('mouseover', (carthover) =>{
            this.carthover = carthover
            $('#shopcartpreview').css('display','block');
        })
    },
    computed: {
        Total: function() {
            var total = 0;
            this.cartitems.forEach(item => {
                total += (item.unit_price * item.qty);
            });
            return total;
        }
    }
}
```

below is the code that I can't get to work properly:

```
  <template>
<div>
    <div id="headerLogo">{{carthover}}<span v-if="carthover"> | {{cartitems[0].name}}</span></div>
    <div id="headerAction">
        <div class="headerActionItem">LOGIN/REGISTER</div>
        <div class="headerActionItem"><img src="assets/images/icon-search.png" width="20px" height="20px"></div>
        <div class="headerActionItem"><img src="assets/images/icon-settings.png" width="20px" height="20px"></div>
        <div class="headerActionItem"><img src="assets/images/icon-love.png" width="20px" height="20px"><a class="floating ui red circular label">0</a></div>
        <div class="headerActionItem" @mouseover="mouseOver"><img src="assets/images/icon-cart.png" width="26px" height="20px"><a class="floating ui red circular label elProduct" id="cartLabel">{{Totall}}</a></div>
    </div>
    <shopcart-preview></shopcart-preview>
</div> 
   </template>

   <script>
module.exports = {
    data: function () {
        return{ 
            cartitems: 0,
            carthover: false
        }
    },
    components: {
        'shopcart-preview': httpVueLoader('components/shopcart-preview.vue')
    },
    created(){ 
        EventBus.$on('addToCart', (payload) =>{
            this.cartitems = payload                
        })
    },
    methods: {
        mouseOver(){ 
            this.carthover = true 
            carthover = true
            EventBus.$emit('mouseover',carthover);
        }
    },
    computed: {
        Totall: function() {
            var totall = 0;
            this.cartitems.forEach(item => {
                totall += (item.unit_price * item.qty);
            });
            return totall;
        }
    }
}
```

The part that isnt working is the following:

```
computed: {
        Totall: function() {
            var totall = 0;
            this.cartitems.forEach(item => {
                totall += (item.unit_price * item.qty);
            });
            return totall;
        }
    }
```

There is a lot of code, but that is to give a full picture of what is happening in code. Perhaps the problem is the result of another part of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.cartitems` is not an Array, and therefore doesnt have the `Array.forEach()` method. This might be because you have set the initial state of cartItems to `0` here

```
data: function () {
        return{ 
            cartitems: 0,
            carthover: false
        }
    },
```

Keep in mind that even if `this.cartItems` is later modified to be an array when you assign `payload` to it, if your `forEach` call runs before the mutation is done, your script will crash.

Comment: Thanks ManavM, changing: cartitems: 0 to cartitems:[] solved the problem!